# SQL Query to find people who bought greater than 3 items in a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to filter out people who bought >=3 games. This is the query I have and I am not able to get the right results and getting an error

```
select PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID,EMAIL,PRODUCT_NAME
from People_who_bought_games
where count(PRODUCT_ID)>=3
```

how to correctly write this? Any help is appreciated

Also tried this query but getting an error,

```
select PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID,EMAIL,PRODUCT_NAME from People_who_bought_games group by CUSTOMER_ID having count(PRODUCT_ID)>=3
```

Comment: Use `HAVING COUNT` instead of `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` `Customer_ID`

Comment: Have you tried using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Adding your table and sample data would be helpful

Comment: tried this but still getting an error: select PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID,EMAIL,PRODUCT_NAME
from People_who_bought_games
group by CUSTOMER_ID
having count(PRODUCT_ID)>=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can write it like this:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID,EMAIL,PRODUCT_NAME 
from People_who_bought_games 
Where CUSTOMER_ID in 
(Select CUSTOMER_ID
FROM People_who_bought_games 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID 
HAVING COUNT(PRODUCT_ID)>=3)
```

Comment: It will give you all peoples, that have 3 or more sales, but you will all Custommer_IDs multiple times as well. Not sure if that is what you need, but let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate and filter you use `having` and you need to `group by` the non-aggregated columns. It would help if you also had some example data and desired results however I would suggest the following

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, EMAIL, PRODUCT_NAME 
from People_who_bought_games 
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, EMAIL, PRODUCT_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have example : You need to use group by and having count functions

```
DECLARE @People_who_bought_games TABLE(
            PRODUCT_ID int,
            CUSTOMER_ID int,
            email VARCHAR(50),
            PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(50)
    )
    
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','111','example@gmail.com','Book'
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','111','example@gmail.com','Book'
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','111','example@gmail.com','Book'
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','111','example@gmail.com','Book'
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','222','example@gmail.com','Book'
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','222','example@gmail.com','Book'
    INSERT INTO @People_who_bought_games SELECT '1','333','example@gmail.com','Book'
    --select 'before' ,* from @Table




SELECT count(*) as NumberBoughtGames,PRODUCT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,email,PRODUCT_NAME
from @People_who_bought_games 
group by PRODUCT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,email,PRODUCT_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
```

The result looks like and shows only record who bought more than 2 games :
[image]